# Issue with magento currencies

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a problems configuring my Magento site

I have added 5k products wit USD prices, but I want them to show EUR on the front-end and the admin panel. I went System->Configuration->Currency Setup and set Default Display Currency to Euro (I also checked Euro as allowed currency lower in the same page), but nothing happens - neither frontend and admin panel changed to EUR. When I change Base Currency to Euro, the prices on the front-end still shows USD, but different value (I understand why). How do I change all prices to Euro without having to change all prices for 5k products?

Comment: Have you made sure that the changes you are making are not getting stuck in in Website Scope switcher, meaning if you are making changes in the Default config but are having values assigned at Store Level

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this the right way? All I did before, was what I wrote about System->Configuration->Currency Setup

Comment: And actually I have two languages and both show different currencies, but I want to change only one

Answer (score 0):

Re-indexing all the indexes becomes necessary in case flat category structure is used.